# BASH: How to resolve paths beginning with file://, sftp://, davs://

Tags: bash, url

I'm writing a bulk rename program to use with [nemo](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/nemo), but nemo passes paths beginning with file://, sftp://, davs://. For example:

- `file:///home/jkoop/my-file.txt`
- `sftp://my-nas/my-file.txt`
- `davs://my-nas/my-file.txt`

How can I resolve these paths to something like:

- `/home/jkoop/my-file.txt`
- `/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp=joek@my-nas/my-file.txt`
- `/run/user/1000/davs=jkoop@my-nas/my-file.txt`

This has been a difficult question to Google. Perhaps something like `realpath` could help?

Comment: So did you check it? Did it help?

Comment: You can use the bash [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) operators to remove or replace these prefixes.

Comment: Stripping `file://` is easy, but in the general case, I would not expect `sftp:` or `davs:` URLs to have any corresponding path on a local filesystem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do conditional pattern substitution.  It is my experience that awk is best for that in both flexibility in defining the patterns to match and specifying the patterns that need to be substituted.

The following fits your example:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "file:///home/jkoop/my-file.txt
sftp://my-nas/my-file.txt
davs://my-nas/my-file.txt
abcdefg://unknown/random/extraneous.txt" |
while [ true ]
do
    read nemopath
    if [ -z "${nemopath}" ] ; then  exit 0 ; fi

    fullpath=`echo "${nemopath}" | 
        awk -v htPref="/"                   \
            -v ftpPref="/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp=joek@" \
            -v davPref="/run/user/1000/davs=jkoop@"     '{
            n=index( $0, "file:///" ) ;
            if( n == 1 ){
                filepath=sprintf("%s%s", htPref, substr($0,9) ) ;
            }else{  
                n=index($0,"sftp://")
                if( n == 1 ){
                    filepath=sprintf("%s%s", ftpPref, substr($0,8) ) ;
                }else{  
                    n=index($0,"davs://")
                    if( n == 1 ){
                        filepath=sprintf("%s%s", davPref, substr($0,8) ) ;
                    }else{
                        filepath=sprintf("#NOMATCH|%s|", $0 ) ;
                    } ;
                } ;
            } ;
        }END{
            print filepath ;
        }' `
    take_action "${nemopath}" "${fullpath}
done
```

That provides the following output (which could be directed to a log file):

```
/home/jkoop/my-file.txt
/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp=joek@my-nas/my-file.txt
/run/user/1000/davs=jkoop@my-nas/my-file.txt
#NOMATCH|abcdefg://unknown/random/extraneous.txt|
```